# Angular - Using a conditional $odd / $even as well as an ng-repeated property with ngClass

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I have an ng-repeat like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
  {{item.text}}
</div>
```

I want to do two things here:

1. If the item is `$odd`, give it a class of "tableOdd"; if `$even`, give it "tableEven".
2. Also add a class to the element referencing `item.ItemStatus`.

For various reasons (this is being used with Angular Material with `md-virtual-repeat` over a table layout), I cannot add an element as a child or parent to this ng-repeat with an additional ng-class on it.

I've tried:

```
  ng-class="{ item.ItemStatus + 'tableEven': $even, 
     item.ItemStatus + 'tableOdd': $odd }"
```

Also tried:

```
  ng-class="{{ $even ? item.ItemStatus + ' tableEven': 
     ($odd ? item.ItemStatus + ' tableOdd': item.ItemStatus) }}"
```

but both give errors. How to best achieve this?

Comment: Please refer this link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd

Answer (score 1):

You can add the class using angular expression based on `ItemStatus` value in each item and then use `ng-class` to add even or add classes like below.

Note the usage of `::` before property name for creating one time binding which means the expressions are realized to values only once. If you want to update your classes by updating `ItemStatus` value in your array, you can remove `::` and use `{{item.ItemStatus}}`

```
<li class="{{::item.ItemStatus}}" ng-repeat="item in data"
        ng-class="{ 'tableEven': $even , 'tableOdd': $odd }">
      {{item.text}}
</li>
```

Here's a sample [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rewBva) in action.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string syntax of ng-class to make it a little more simple. For example:

```
<div ng-class="item.itemStatus + ($even ? ' classOdd' : ' classEven')"></div>
```

Also, you might be interested in [ngClassEven](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassEven) and [ngClassOdd](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd). They work in conjunction with ngRepeat and allow you to set a class for an item based on whether it is even or odd.

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in data" ng-class-odd="'tableOdd ' + item.ItemStatus" ng-class-even="'tableEven ' + item.ItemStatus">
      {{item.text}}
  </div>
```

Here's a useful post of the [many ways of using ngClass](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass).